# Combining 2 collections after filtering 2nd one based on ids from first one

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections like this:

Batches:

```
{
  "userId": "",
  "productId: "",
}
```

Products:

```
{
   "_id": "",
   "name": "",
}
```

What i want to do is filter the batches by `userId` first. And then get all products which i get ids in filtered elements of batches. I have seen a lot of examples but mostly goes the opposite way.

My final result i would like to look like this:

```
[{
   name: "product 1",
   batches: [...]
}]
```

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try [lookup with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries),

- `$lookup` in branches collection, pass `productId` in `let`, and match expression condition for for `productId` and filter `userId`

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "branches",
      let: { productId: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            userId: "1", // filter user id here
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$productId", "$productId"] }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "brnaches"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ih8s9mahuyH)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
mongos> db.Batches.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff9a66fda146da4e1359dc9"), "userId" : "User1", "productId" : "product1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff9a675da146da4e1359dca"), "userId" : "User2", "productId" : "product1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff9a682da146da4e1359dcb"), "userId" : "User3", "productId" : "product2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff9a6deda146da4e1359dcc"), "userId" : "User3", "productId" : "product1" }
mongos> db.Products.find()
{ "_id" : "product1", "name" : "product 1" }
{ "_id" : "product2", "name" : "product 2" }
{ "_id" : "product3", "name" : "product 3" }
{ "_id" : "product4", "name" : "product 4" }
mongos> db.Batches.aggregate([ {$match:{"userId":{$in:["User3","User1"]}}},  { $lookup:{ from:"Products" , localField:"productId" , foreignField:"_id" , as:"match"    }  } , {$unwind:"$match"}  , {$project:{ name:"$match.name" , batches :{userId:"$userId" , productId:"$productId"}  }}  , {$group:{_id:"$name" , batches:{$addToSet:"$batches"}}} , {$project:{_id:0, name:"$_id" , batches:1}}  ])
{ "batches" : [ { "userId" : "User1", "productId" : "product1" }, { "userId" : "User3", "productId" : "product1" } ], "name" : "product 1" }
{ "batches" : [ { "userId" : "User3", "productId" : "product2" } ], "name" : "product 2" }
mongos>
```